# Windows 11 On-Screen Keyboard partially displayed, missing keys

Tags: windows, windows-11

I have a touch screen Windows machine with multiple user accounts, for one single user the on-screen keyboard isn't displaying most of the keys.

I only found [one other reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/incomplete-on-screen-keyboard/f4c85fe6-8915-42c3-a93d-4c2eef9b6d38) to this issue online.

My last resort will just be creating another account for the user and moving their data across but it'd be easier if there was a solution to this.

[image]

Comment: It is in this case a user profile error.  These are not easily fix so save your documents and build a new user profile

Comment: Does that user have the game *Spore* installed?

Comment: Have you tried to make the window larger? It appears the window has been made long horizontally but smaller vertically

Comment: @Ramhound yeah I certainly have.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik no, I did see that reference else where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the same problem which I was able to resolve. I clicked on the "general" button on the glitched keyboard and it restored all the on screen keyboard keys! It has been working for a while now without any more problems. Did you try clicking on the general button? if not please do so! I hope this helps, I had a very hard time signing up here to answer this question for you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help a random internet stranger, that's exactly it!!!! Just saved me setting up a new user account next week, Cheers.

Comment: No problem, I am glad it worked for you too. I have too much installed on my pc to delete my user account so I was going to try installing a 3rd party on screen keyboard program instead.  Thankfully it is working again :)